# Is there a way to generate all pyc files in Pycharm for a Python project?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am looking for is it possible to generate all the pyc files from python code in Pycharm. Just like the build all function in visual studio.

I can't find it in Pycharm so far. Do you know pycharm provide this function or not? Or any workaround?
Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html ?  But why would you want to do this?  Python bytecompiles on the fly.  Are you really seeing a lag from byte compiling? And presumably you're using an ide because you want to *develop* code, not run it.  But python will re-bytecompile on the fly as you edit anyhow: bytecompiling *everything* would be slower than just recompiling as needed.

Comment: we just don't want to deploy the plain text source code. I know pyc is also not that secure, but our customers are not professional. It is quite enough to deploy pyc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I question the wisdom of this: if your customers aren't professionals, they probably can't read the code meaningfully anyhow.  But decisions like this are often out of your control. I'd use compileall as part of a dedicated build step to make sure no .py files got through

Comment: thanks all for your reply. deploy pyc is just a workaround so that people can't read the source code easily.
I tried compileall and it can do what I need, even though it is not in pycharm.
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I use the command `python -m compileall . -f` and it can do what I need.
Thanks all.